# Sequence of events and independence

Tags: probability, independence

Assume we have a car and a bike. We know the initial, but not future positions of the bike and the current and future positions of the car. Moreover, the bike can only cover a finite distance in one step.  For  each of the $N$ steps, we can have the events $S_i$ (no collision in step $i$) and $F_i$ (collision in step $i$). Further, say that as soon as $F_i$ occurs for the first time, we stop the experiment. Lastly, let $P(S_i)$ and $P(F_i)$ denote the respective probabilities.

I want to check if 
$$ P(S_1,S_2,...,S_N) = \prod_{i=1}^{N}P(S_i). $$

For this to hold, I e.g. need that 
$$ P(S_2|S_1) = P(S_2). $$

I am somewhat struggling with it: The only thing I know from $S_1$ occuring in step one is that car and bike are at least not touching, that is not colliding. In other words, they have to be a certain distance apart. But I feel like calculating $P(S_2)$ already implies that $S_1$ occured. Does it make sense to say that only $P(S_2|S_1)$ exists, but not $P(S_2)$ itself?

Comment: This is not clear.  Since the event $S_n$ requires the events $S_1,\cdots, S_{n-1}$ we have $P(S_1,\cdots, S_{n})=P(S_n)$.  Or have I misread?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I thought the probablity of no collision in each step was $P(S_i)$, but in reality it is $P(S_i|S_{i-1},S_{i-2},..)$. Because if I do not assume that no collision occured in the previous steps, it doesn't really make sense to try to calculate the probability. It would either not exist or be zero since I know that a collision occured. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure.  I'd say the event $S_n$ wasn't even defined unless we had $S_1,\cdots, S_{n-1}$ but I can see where you might say it was defined with probability $0$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!